# Unable to login to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am unable to login to Bluemix GUI using the browser. I am getting "Internal server error" or getting the following message.

```
{"error_description":"Failed to connect to UAA. Details: 404 Not Found: Requested route ('uaa.ng.bluemix.net') does not exist.\n","error":"unauthorized"}
```

Even the client support site(link below) seems to be not working. The "Service Offering" dropdown is not getting populated in "Open Ticket" Dialog box

https://support.ibmcloud.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptid=31036&offering=ibmbluemix

Answer (score 1):

The log in issues in the US South region were resolved at 03:11 UTC on July 8th. This update was published to the [Bluemix Status Page](http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus).

Answer (score 0):

Arindam, currently there are issues with US-South region and IBM team is working on this issue. As of now some application routes are coming back online. The operations team is continuing work toward full resolution. For further updates, please check the status page at https://status.au-syd.bluemix.net/